# Why can't I include a blur radius on JavaScript boxShadow?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use Javascript to put a box-shadow on an HTML element. However, I can't blur the shadow. Here is the JS:

```
document.addEventListener('input', function() {
  let box = document.getElementById('mainBox');
  let blurRadius = document.getElementById('blurRadius');

  box.style.boxShadow = '0px 0px ' + blurRadius.value + ' rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
});
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div id="mainBox">
   <input type="range" id="blurRadius">
</div>
```

Comment: changing the value of your input doesn't run the code - there is no data binding between the value of the input and the box.style - you'll need to add an event listener to the input, and run your code when the value changes

Comment: the JS is inside a function that is called with an event listener

Comment: You need an unit (probably `px`)

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't work either

Comment: yes it does: https://jsfiddle.net/a1bc90rx/

Comment: @pineapplerind0215 perhaps you should show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) rather than code that looks incorrect

Comment: wow, for some reason it didn't work when I tried it

Comment: @JaromandaX done

Comment: Your Event is on the `document`. Should be like  `const box = document.getElementById('mainBox'); document.getElementById('blurRadius').oninput = function(){  box.style.boxShadow = '0px 0px ' + this.value + ' rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'; }`. Of course, I really recommend just setting a predefined CSS class with `Element.classList.add('yourClassHere')` instead.

Comment: @StackSlave input event bubbles, you can catch it from document just fine. And are you really gonna add +Infinity classes to match all the possible values from that range without a step?

Comment: @Kaiido, OP never shows intent to affect multiple Elements. Would you really want a process to run every time there is an input, even if unnecessary?

Comment: Still that definitely is not the issue they faced here. And yes, I do delegate as much events as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding an event listener to input and using 'this'. 'this' returns the input element.

```
document.getElementById('blurRadius').addEventListener("change", function() {
    let box = document.getElementById('box'); 
    box.style.boxShadow = '1px 1px ' + this.value + 'px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';  
});
```